# PHP strings and tick marks

Tags: php, html, string, concatenation

Trying to add [this](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) query mobile date picker to my page.  I am using PHP to create the form of each page, so I am doing a lot of string concatenation.  The format for this date picker looks like this:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>
```

So I have a line that looks like this:

```
$form .= '<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>';
```

The tick marks around the curly brackets are causing problems.  I have tried escaping them with extra ticks such as:

```
data-options='''{"mode".....}'''
```

and faking it out with:

```
data-options=&#39;{"mode"....}&#39;
```

can't make it work, help much appreciated.

Comment: ok it works, thanks to everyone, thought I had tried that but guess not lol.

Comment: The full manual on PHP strings [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). The main example gives it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape quotes with a \, like this:

```
$form .= '<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "calbox"}\'>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$form .= '<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode": "calbox"}\'>';
```

This will work fine.